# Flattening two JSON with different data types and joining them

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to flatten two JSON files (let's call them `JSON1` & `JSON2`). Below is an example of how they look.

Now in one file, the column data type could be struct while in the other it is a string. The end goal is to be able to flatten these files and combine/join/merge the data into a CSV file. How can this be done in Spark using Python?

**JSON1:**

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "promoted_by": "",
            "parent": "",
            "number": "310346",
            "closed_by": {
                "link": "https://abcdev.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user/e4b0dd",
                "value": "e4b0dd"
            }
        }
    ]
}

root
 |-- result: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- closed_by: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- link: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- number: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- parent: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- promoted_by: string (nullable = true)
```

**JSON2:**

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "promoted_by": "",
            "parent": {
                "link": "https://abcdev.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user/ab00f1",
                "value": "ab00f1"
            },
            "number": "310348",
            "closed_by": ""
        }
    ]
}

root
 |-- result: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- closed_by: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- number: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- parent: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- link: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- promoted_by: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Have you tried to read these 2 files in a single data frame? You should get the schemas merged by Spark.

Comment: Wouldn't it get overwritten? Like this I read the files in a df1 like as follows, df1 = spark.read.json("dbfs:/mnt/json1.json") and then I do df1 = spark.read.json("dbfs:/mnt/json2.json")

Comment: @blackbishop, please put this as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply read the 2 JSON files into the same DataFrame. The schemas will be merged automatically by Spark. Columns `closed_by` and `parent` will both be of type `struct`:

```
df = spark.read.json("dbfs:/mnt/{json1.json,json2.json}", multiLine=True)

df.printSchema()

#root
# |-- result: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
# |    |    |-- closed_by: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |    |    |-- link: string (nullable = true)
# |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- number: string (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- parent: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |    |    |-- link: string (nullable = true)
# |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- promoted_by: string (nullable = true)
```

To flatten the structure, use `explode` + star expand the structs:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.select(F.explode("result").alias("results")).select("results.*") \
        .select(
        F.col("number"),
        F.col("closed_by.value").alias("closed_by_value"),
        F.col("closed_by.link").alias("closed_by_link"),
        F.col("parent.value").alias("parent_value"),
        F.col("parent.link").alias("parent_link"),
        F.col("promoted_by")
    )

df1.printSchema()

#root
# |-- number: string (nullable = true)
# |-- closed_by_value: string (nullable = true)
# |-- closed_by_link: string (nullable = true)
# |-- parent_value: string (nullable = true)
# |-- parent_link: string (nullable = true)
# |-- promoted_by: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Let's say if the JSON structure changes in the future, lets says the promoted_by column is of type struct or column parent is of type string